how to load a template in unlayer-react-email-editor
<EmailEditor ref={emailEditorRef} onReady={onTemplateReady} />
const onTemplateReady = () => {
    try {
      const templateJson = htmlToJSON(savedData?.email?.content);
      console.log({ templateJson });
      emailEditorRef?.current?.editor?.loadDesign(templateJson);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading template:", error);
    }
  };
export const htmlToJSON = (html) => {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

  const parseNode = (node) => {
    const jsonNode = {
      tagName: node.tagName.toLowerCase(),
      attributes: {},
      children: []
    };

    for (const { name, value } of node.attributes) {
      jsonNode.attributes[name] = value;
    }

    for (const childNode of node.childNodes) {
      if (childNode.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        jsonNode.children.push(parseNode(childNode));
      } else if (childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        jsonNode.children.push(childNode.nodeValue);
      }
    }

    return jsonNode;
  };

  return parseNode(doc.body);
};

Not able to load the template design why? I am not getting what I am doing wrong.Is there any problem with the conversion of html data to json format.how to load a template in unlayer-react-email-editor. Any leads would be appriciated.

Anubhav Garg You can try using this approach using native js.
https://docs.unlayer.com/docs/export-html
Unlayer email edior export the designs in both html and json.

You need to export the json as well as HTML
Use HTML to send your email
While loading the image you have load using json

It'll work like magic.
Thank me later

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
